# Tick selected option-element

Tags: html

this is probably a very basic question, but I can't seem to figure it out. 
In the code below you can see that I have a select-option block. It works fine. The only problem is that when I select one of the options (and get redirected to the corresponding page), the **tick** remains at the default value ("Sort...") of the select-option function.

```
 <select name="sort" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">  
    <option value="">Sort...</option>
    <option value="index.php?ascending=true">Preis aufsteigend</option>
    <option value="index.php?descending=true">Preis absteigend</option>
   </select>
```

When a user selects "Preis aufsteigend", I would like the **tick** to be displayed at the corresponding option in the field...

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What 'tick' are you referring to?

Comment: √ <-- just the simple tick you get when you choose an option from a select-field. It's just in the wrong place in my case. It always remains at the "Sort..."-Value, even when I choose option 2 or 3 (just like when no option has been selected)

Comment: @George He means `selected`

Comment: that's what I mean! sorry. I imagine it must be a quite simple matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse your `onchange` function. On page load look for the url variable you set then select the appropriate option.

Script

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sort');
var opts = sel.options;
for(var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
    if(window.location.search.indexOf(opt.value.split('?')[1]) > -1 ) {
        sel.selectedIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="sort" name="sort" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">  
    <option value="">Sort...</option>
    <option value="index.php?ascending=true">Preis aufsteigend</option>
    <option value="index.php?descending=true">Preis absteigend</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t95wqm48/